# C#: Прямой доступ к свойству класса

Tags: c#, классы, доступ

Добрый день! Есть ли какой нибудь способ организовать доступ к свойству класса таким образом:

```
public class Test
{ public int iValue; }
...
Test a = new a();
a = 5; //данная строка присваивает значение на прямую iValue
```

Вариант с `public object this[int indexer]` не подходит, интересует именно доступ на запись свойства через равенство. Заранее благодарю Вас, за проявленное внимание!

Comment: Хм. А _зачем_ вам это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще затея довольно странная. Но сделать так можно. Для этого есть оператор неявного преобразования и возможность его перегрузки с помощью ключевых слов **operator** и **implicit**. Пример:

```
public class Test
{
    public int iValue;

    public static implicit operator Test (int val)
    {
        return new Test { iValue = val };
    }
}

....

Test a = new Test();
a = 5; // тут срабатывает перегруженный оператор
```

Для преобразования вашего класса  в int можно добавить еще одну перегрузку этого оператора:

```
public static implicit operator int(Test val)
{
    return val.iValue;
}
```

Еще можно отметить "обратный" ему оператор **explicit**, позволяющий выполнять явное преобразование вида (int)Test, работающий аналогично

Comment: Благодарю, за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Опишите неявное преобразование:

```
public static implicit operator Test(int value)
{
    return new Test {iValue = value};

}
```